# Firefox and Chromium won't display pages correctly

Tags: firefox

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS so I’m quite new with this OS, so please be patient with me.

My Firefox and Chromium was updated when Ubuntu asked to update in software updater, but now I can't view pages correctly anymore eg: Facebook, YouTube, IMDb, and many others. (Current Firefox version 37.0.1)

I just see text but everything else is just white. I have cleared my browsing history, cache and all that but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you try running Firefox in safe mode? It could be problem with FF extension or plugins.

Comment: check  if javascript is enable in your browser

Comment: Okay so i did run in safemode, still the same, and my Javascript is on. No difference.

Comment: Or use a more simple page like http://www.google.com and post a screenshot of this.